# Call block of type core/text_list inside Static Block or CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, static-block

Is there any way or work-around for getting the content of "core/text_list" type block into CMS Homepage, with least possible changes ?

The "core/text_list" type block contains two banner sliders one wide banner and another narrow banner slider. It is defined in the local.xml file of custom theme like below:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="preface" as="preface" translate="label">
            <label>Preface</label>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I want to call that block of type "core/text_list" in Homepage content which is defined in cms page.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Where is this list block defined? What are the children?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can not reference other existing blocks within a static block. A static block is, by definition *static* and does not depend on external state

You can however instantiate and render other blocks inside a static block, but you have to be careful with that, see: [CMS Block Cache issue with included dynamic template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82793/cms-block-cache-issue-with-included-dynamic-template/105136#105136)

That means you can include the banners one by one using `{{block}}` directives, if they don't need any `<action>`s.